# "No template named 'variant' in namespace 'std'" in Android Studio

Tags: c++, android-studio, cmake, c++17

It's weird because it does recognise it in another project that I have.
Here's the `CMakeLists.txt` fo; for the project where I get the error:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Require C++17 compiler with no extensions
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

(...)
```

And the one where it does recognise `std::variant` is pretty much the same (in fact I copied it):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Require C++17 compiler with no extensions
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/..)

(...)
```

The installed versions of CMake in my Android Studio are 3.6.4111459 and 3.10.2.
I have included `<variant>` as well, and it has no problem with it, but still doesn't recognise `std::variant`.
The project builds, however Android Studio still highlights it in red.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't specified Gradle the version of CMake that I wanted to use. `std::variant` is not supported in older versions of CMake. So I went to `build.gradle` and did this:

```
(...)

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"        // I ADDED THIS
        }
    }

(...)
```